# L'Académie a-t-elle eu raison d'imposer en 1539 l'orthographe de "ù" ?

Tags: orthographe

Le seul mot français utilisant le "**ù**" est "**où**" (en faisant abstraction des mots étrangers comme l'italien *più*). Une demi-touche du clavier AZERTY ne sert qu'à cela.

L'explication courante est qu'il faut distinguer la conjonction "ou" de l'adverbe "où" ; mais existe-t-il un contexte réel ou *[faute volontaire]* elle soit possible (Beaumarchais en a trouvé un, mais été chercher un peu loin) ?

Ne pourrait-on supprimer le "ù" de la langue, à la rigueur le remplacer par "û", comme pour "du" et "dû" - où une confusion est également bien improbable ?

Il faut admettre que les étymologies sont radicalement différentes : "aut" et "ubi", mais les prononciations sont devenues les mêmes.

"Aut" est un "ou exclusif" ; "ou" est ambigu, parce que "vel" latin, ou inclusif, tellement commode, a disparu en français, et il faut préciser "ou bien", le "et/ou" n'étant toléré que dans les textes scientifiques. Garder cette distinction par un accent n'aurait-elle pas supprimé bien de lourdes circonlocutions ?

**Question** : existe-t-il une justification ?

Comment: Je n'avais pas remarqué dans les défilants (et cela me surprenait) ; où la trouver ?

Comment: Trouvé par "search", interrogé antérieurement avec trop de précision, et reformulé le titre.